# Why doesn't quantity group by dimension?

Tags: ssas

Very simple question.

I have created a multi-dimensional model for SQL Server Analysis Services in Visual Studio. But I can't get why my relations in data model don't work.

For example
this is how relations look like

[see data relations model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goadl.png)

Sales is related to Item-Current on [WWI Stock Item ID]

It should work.

But when I try to calculate [Sales].[Quantity] by [Items-Current].[Color], I get a wrong result.

[see wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TefgG.png)

What did I do wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the issue is that your dimension key is different than the key used to link it with the fact (Dimension Key = Stock Item Key, Dimension attribute that is used to link with fact: WWI Stock Item ID). That is why it is not linking properly. you can solve this in 2 ways:

1 Make WWI Stock Item ID your dimension's primary key
2 In the dimension attribute relationships, connect the color attribute to WWI Stock Item ID and remove the relationship between color and Stock Item Key)